# Play Store app download 100% then starts over to 0%

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, download-manager

I can successfully download small apps like solitaire, but when I try to download larger apps/games that are 65 MB large, it downloads 100% then it starts over until I go in and cancel the download.

I have plenty of room on my phone and it can download apps (like booster, cache cleaner, etc) from other websites. I also have restarted my phone.

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to clear your Play Store data, by accessing the app's info from your phone's **Settings**, and tapping on **Clear Data**. Please note that you'll have to reconfigure the Play Store's settings, afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear cache of Playstore and download manager from Apps setting. and then restart your mobile.
I have done through this way, bro.

Answer (score 0):

The 65MB thing is the APK of the app. An APK is a type of file which we can install on our devices.

The other thing is the additional file or the OBB. We cannot install OBB on our devices because it is a huge file and it would not be able to run in most of the devices. Therefore, Play Store uses this method. This process is completely normal and happens with everybody.

Let's assume that you download an app of 300 MB. The first 100%, Play Store would download the APK of the app. The next 100%, it'll show you, "Additional File for: XYZGAME" where it actually downloads the OBB file.

Answer (score 0):

1. There Probable Causes Of Your Issue :-
2. Your device doesn't have enough space
3. Your device is Lagging (e.g Lower RAM)
4. Playstore is Misbehaving

You can try :-
1. Clear Complete Cache Of Playstore and data and then do fresh sign in with your existing email or new. 2. And make sure PlayStore is Updated. 3. Try Force Stopping PlayStore, it may also help..

If none of above solutions work and you want that App badly then you can try some Populer and even better PlayStore alternetive like Amazon App Store, Uptodown App Store or several like this (Check on Google for more Stores)..

Answer (score -3):

It's the Play Store itself. Either download an old update back in 2015 variant or try the newer ones for 8.1+ Android devices